# PHP build a specific JSON string from postgresql Database

Tags: php, string, postgresql, json

I want use zachhunters json to html tabel script with my postressql db so i need a specific JSON string format but i dont know how to build it ... (i am new in json)

[Link to the Script](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table)

I get my data using

```
$result = pg_fetch_array($rs, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
```

When i use `json_encode($result)` i get this:

```
{"id":"2","surname":"Max","name":"Muster"} etc.
```

For the Script i need somthing like:

```
{ "d": "[{\"id\":1,\"Username\":\"Sam Smith\"},{\"id\":2,\"UserName\":\"Fred Frankly\"}]" }
```

How can i handle this?

Comment: I highly doubt that you need JSON containing a JSON string. You probably need JSON containing an array containing your row objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each loop where you fetch an element from your database store the `$result` in an array `$rows`.

After the loop simply use `json_encode(array('d' => $rows))` to create JSON containing all your data.